# How to wait for all completed AsyncOperations on app close

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, abi

I'm sending messages using an asynchronous write operation, but when the app is closed I need to write 2 messages to a device, but only 1 message gets successfully written.

Each write operation is chained to a message queue, so the messages write operations are sent sequentially after each completed write operation while the message queue is full. So basically the following code might get to the first completed callback, but it doesn't reach the 2nd before the app closes. I tried adding a Windows `Sleep` call in between and after Async Operations, but this didn't work. I also tested waiting for the completion callback using a while loop to see if the 2nd opertation ever completes, which it never does.

```
    ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<GattCommunicationStatus>> writeOp;
    GattWriteOption option = GattWriteOption_WriteWithoutResponse;
    hr = customCharacteristic->WriteValueWithOptionAsync(buffer.Get(), option, &writeOp);
    hr = writeOp->put_Completed(Callback<IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<GattCommunicationStatus>>
                (this, &DataGloveBluetooth::OnCharacteristicWriteComplete).Get());
```

This is only an issue on app close as it seems 2nd operation never gets to the callback. Also, the messages are too large to put together, so I need to be able to send more than 1 message.

Is there a proper way I can wait? This is some pseudo-code to help explain the ordering:

```
WriteMessage(LED_RESET); // adds to message queue, then calls aync op, 
WriteMessage(CLOSE); // adds to message queue, async op is called once first message is sent, complete callback is never reached
Sleep(5000) // whatever sleep amount never helps the 2nd message finish
```

Comment: Are you in fact using C++/WinRT, though? The code seems to be accessing the raw COM interfaces with a bit of WRL.

Comment: I'm using the ABI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-abi

Comment: I'm confused. C++/WinRT is a language projection, so that you do not have to deal with the ABI. Also, `ComPtr` isn't a C++/WinRT class template. So again, do you have access to C++/WinRT?

Comment: Just the ABI. I'm working lower level for a DLL.